# Filter values in range loop in golang

Tags: go

I’ve the following code which runs ok, Im looping on the `mStr` and printing
Value to a file

```
func setFile(file io.Writer, mStr []*mod.M, mdl []string) {

    for i, mod := range mStr {
            fmt.Fprint(file, “app”)
            fmt.Fprint(file, “app1”)
                        …

    }
}
```

Now what I need is to provide a filter on the range ,
e.g. just prints to file  if mod.Name ==“app”

```
func setFile(file io.Writer, mStr []*mod.M, mdl []string) {

    for i, mod := range mStr {

    if mod.Name == mdl[i] {
            fmt.Fprint(file, “app”)
            fmt.Fprint(file, “app1”)
                        …

    }
  }
}
```

While this could work, it introduce a few `if else` forks in the code to support the following :

1. If `mdl` is **empty** (it can be without any value)loop on all the mStr value and prints to all.
2. If  mdl contain value , prints only when the `mod.Name == mdl[I]`  otherwise don’t.

Is there a **cleaner** way to do this kind of filtering on loop in Golang?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using if else when checking for empty slice.

Comment: @Himanshu - so how would you write it ? :) can you provide it as answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Check for length of slice that you are passing in the function if the slice is empty it will give the length as zero.

```
if len(mdl) > 0 && mod.Name == mdl[i] {
        fmt.Fprint(file, “app”)
        fmt.Fprint(file, “app1”)
        // code
}else{
     // code
}
```

Comment: According to the question that should be `i >= len(mdl) || mod.Name == mdl[i]`; handle either matching values, or all of them if `mdl` is empty.

Comment: @Peter this condition will fail when `i=0` because `mdl` length will be zero and the code will run even if the slice is empty. and it will not check for second condition if first will meet it will run the code.

Comment: The code is supposed to run when the slice is empty: "1. If mdl is empty (it can be without any value)loop on all the mStr value and prints to all."

Comment: @Peter What if the slice is not empty first condition will be true then the code should run for those values of slice which is equal to `mod.Name`. But your option will run for every value because second condition need not to be true.

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to say. If `mdl` is not empty the first condition will only ever be true if `mStr` is larger than `mdl`. It prevents an out-of-bounds panic while also covering the first goal of the OP.

Comment: @Peter I am not getting can you help me regenerate the condition you are saying. I am getting confused. Because if first condition is true should condition should also be true. if its wrong the loop will continue to next iteration. But in your case it will print the value even if second condition is false.